# Prune baby kumquat (citrus) tree

Tags: pruning, citrus

Just for the fun of it I threw a kumquat seed in a pot, and it has actually grow quite a bit. I know you should ideally graft cuttings onto rootstock and not start from seed. But I just did it for the fun of it.

Now I wonder if I should start pruning it? When I transplanted It to the current pot I cut the top of cuz I lost many roots moving it, so it has now got two main branches. 
While it has grown quite tall (about 1meter) it's not thicker than a pencil.

Should I cut it down, or let it continue growing?

[image]

Comment: Is this kumquat growing indoors or is it outside? Any chance of a photograph?

Comment: @Bamboo It's growing outdoors in Barcelona Spain. Receiving about 3 hours direct sunlight, but is in a very bright spot with light reflecting of surrounding buildings.

Answer (score 2):

Usually Kumquat trees in pot are about < 1 m in height. In the far east they are put in front of the door to welcome you. [This](https://www.google.nl/search?nord=1&dcr=0&biw=1920&bih=971&tbm=isch&sa=1&q=kumquat%20tree&oq=kumquat%20tree&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0l10.2503.3267.0.3418.5.5.0.0.0.0.50.217.5.5.0....0...1.1.64.psy-ab..0.5.217...0i67k1.0.Vk95a7SSeSA#imgrc=SwaUg65nbkUepM:) is what an average Kumquat tree looks like in a pot, way shorter and more compact than your tree is now.

The reason is probably, like Bamboo already said, not enough sunlight. Plants tend to get long and thin in search of light. So pruning would help to get your plant fuller and compacter. But if your tree will ever carry fruits, I am not sure. But it is worth a try!

Answer (score 0):

It really needs to be in full sun - because its not, that's why its grown in this fashion, its etiolated. I suspect it needs a bigger pot, but you can check by turning it out to see whether the roots have filled the whole thing or not - if they've haven't just replace it, if they have, a larger pot.

According to this http://oureverydaylife.com/grow-kumquat-tree-kumquat-seed-5477481.html pruning isn't necessary, but you can prune if you like, so I'd suggest you check the roots, repot if necessary, then cut it down by half. This may force another stem from the base, so you get a twin trunked tree, but its not worth cutting it back if you cannot increase its sun exposure, because it will grow in the same way it has now.

If you can sort out its sun exposure, and can pot on as necessary, you should get fruit in 7 years, even without grafting it onto another rootstock.